# Testing whether lambda expression returns true for any list element

Tags: elisp

I have the following function defined in my `.emacs` to test if a given executable exists within my `$PATH`. I implemented it with `cl-reduce` and the code looks really unidiomatic (to me).

```
(defun executable-in-path-p (executable)
  "Test if EXECUTABLE exists in path."
  (eq t (cl-reduce
         (lambda (path exists)
           (or (file-exists-p (concat (file-name-as-directory path) executable))
               exists))
         exec-path)))
```

Is there a more concise way to test if a list, mapped with a predicate function, has at least one element equal to `t` than this?

```
(eq t
    (cl-reduce
     (lambda (element acc)
       (or (some-check-p element)
           acc))
     some-list))
```

In Ruby for example I would write:

```
some_list.any? { |element| some_check(element) }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you already have Common Lisp-derived functions in there, use [`CL-SOME`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/cl.html#index-cl_002dsome) instead:

```
(defun executable-in-path-p (executable)
  "Test if EXECUTABLE exists in path."
  (cl-some (lambda (path) (file-exists-p (concat (file-name-as-directory path) executable))) exec-path))
```

That's of course a little bit different than explicitly checking for `t`, but you shouldn't be doing that anyway in most cases ([everything but `nil` is already true](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Truth-_0026-Falsehood.html)).

Comment: Thanks, that looks really clean. I agree, checking for _truthy_ values feels a lot more idiomatic than checking vor `t` explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Apply `'file-exists-p` on the list of files and check whether true is a member of the result:

```
(member t (mapcar 'file-exists-p list-of-files))
```